# Only divide button is working properly in JavaScript calculator. "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" errors for other operators

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a working calculator until I added an equation history line to the display output. Now the only operator that works properly is the divide button.

When I perform a division equation (for example, 8/9), it works the way I want it to. The top row of the display output only shows the current number or operator (or answer, if the problem is complete), and then the bottom row shows the full equation. However, when I try to do anything besides division, the calculator doesn't work properly.

Instead, it shows the full equation on both the top and bottom, and when I hit the equals button I get the following error message in the console:

```
"Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined"
```

This leads me to believe that my Regex to truncate the numbers after a decimal is causing the problem, but it was working earlier before I added the `equation` variable. I also don't get why division is the only operator that is functioning properly. Can someone explain why this is happening and/or what I'm doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qLL2u2m/1/)

Comment: Problem is that `if($('.operator, #decimal').data('clicked'))` returns only the clicked status of the first operator button found. So this is only true when the divide button was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer of you first issues of why other operation not working.

1: you are checking  **if($('.operator, #decimal').data('clicked'))** which will give the first matching operator and will work only for divide.

2: when an operator is clicked you are setting

```
$(this).data('clicked', true);
```

that means the point 1 and point 2 will talk about different operators in case of other than divide.

I have tried to fix it with setting operator test on an operator button click and check for it if its empty and make it empty on equal button click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num = "", operator = "", num2 = "", equation = "";
    var output = $("#output");
    output.text("0");
    var history = $("#history");
    history.text("0");

    $('.numbers').click(function() {
        if(operator !== "") {
          num2 += this.value;
          equation = num + num2;
          output.text(num2);
          history.text(equation);
        } else {
          num += this.value;
          output.text(num);
          history.text(num);
        }
        checkOperator();
        checkLimit();
    });

    $('.operator, #decimal').click(function() {
    
      $(this).data('clicked', true);
      num += this.value;
      operator = this.value;
      output.text(operator);
      history.text(num);
      checkOperator();
    });

    // checks if last input was an operator and prevents two from being used twice in a row
    function checkOperator() {
      if (num.slice(-1) === "+" || num.slice(-1) === "-" || num.slice(-1) === "/" || num.slice(-1) === "*") {
        $(".operator").attr("disabled", true);
      } else if (num.slice(-1) === ".") {
        $("#decimal").attr("disabled", true);
      } else {
        $(".operator").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#decimal").removeAttr("disabled");
        history.text(num);
      }
    };

    function checkLimit() {
      if (num.length > 10) {
        num = "";
        num2 = "";
        operator = "";
        output.text("0");
        history.text("Digit Limit Reached");
      }
    };

    $('#ac').click(function() {
        num = "";
        num2 = "";
        equation = "";
        operator = "";
        output.text("0");
        history.text("0");
        operator="";
    });

    $('#ce').click(function() {
        num = num.slice(0, -1);
        if (num === "") {
          output.text("0");
          history.text("0");
        } else {
          output.text(num);
          history.text(num);
        }
    });

    $('#equals').click(function() {
      num = eval(equation);
      num = num.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,8})?/)[0];
      output.text(num);
      history.text(equation + " = " + num);
      operator = "";
      num2 = "";
      $(".operator").removeAttr("disabled");
    });

    $(document).keypress(function(event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode === 49) {
          $("#one").click();
        } else if (keycode === 50) {
          $("#two").click();
        } else if (keycode === 51) {
          $("#three").click();
        } else if (keycode === 52) {
          $("#four").click();
        } else if (keycode === 53) {
          $("#five").click();
        } else if (keycode === 54) {
          $("#six").click();
        } else if (keycode === 55) {
          $("#seven").click();
        } else if (keycode === 56) {
          $("#eight").click();
        } else if (keycode === 57) {
          $("#nine").click();
        } else if (keycode === 48) {
          $("#zero").click();
        } else if (keycode === 97) {
          $("#ac").click();
        } else if (keycode === 99) {
          $("#ce").click();
        } else if (keycode === 61 || keycode === 13 || keycode === 187) {
          $("#equals").click();
        } else if (keycode === 43) {
          $("#add").click();
        } else if (keycode === 45) {
          $("#subtract").click();
        } else if (keycode === 42 || keycode === 120) {
          $("#multiply").click();
        } else if (keycode === 47) {
          $("#divide").click();
        } else if (keycode === 110 || keycode === 190) {
          $("#decimal").click();
        }
    });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 10px auto;
}
body {
  background-color: #202020;
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;

}
#screen {
  background: #94AFB5;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#history {
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.calculator {
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 410px;
  height: 550px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: #5591C3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
button {
  margin: 2px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #084D87;
  color: #D17900;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #053C6A;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
button:active {
  background-color: #084D87;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #053C6A;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
#zero {
  width: 181px;
}
#ac, #ce {
  background-color: #EC0000;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #BC0000;
  color: #814B00;
}
.last-row {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 31px;
}
#equals {
  height: 125px;
  font-size: 45px;
}
.footer {
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #D17900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="calculator">
      <h3>ELECTRONIC CALCULATOR</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div id="screen" class="text-right">
          <div id="output" class="text-right"></div>
          <div id="history" class="text-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="ac">AC</button>
        <button id="ce">CE</button>
        <button class="operator" id="divide" value="/">&divide;</button>
        <button class="operator" id="multiply" value="*">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="numbers" id="seven" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="numbers" id="eight" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="numbers" id="nine" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="operator" id="subtract" value="-">-</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="numbers" id="four" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="numbers" id="five" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="numbers" id="six" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="operator" id="add" value="+">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="numbers" id="one" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="numbers" id="two" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="numbers" id="three" value="3">3</button>
        <button id="equals">=</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row last-row">
        <button class="numbers" id="zero" value="0">0</button>
        <button id="decimal" value=".">.</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/27rprs1g/

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! I wasn't aware `.data` only pulled the first matching operator. I believe I know where to go from here, too, in getting the other operations to work continuously.

Comment: @wildlifehexagon Glad to help , do check out the  edited fiddle link which will work for continuous operation as well.

Answer (score 0):

the object wich you give to the function toString is undefined aka not created. Please show us the code part(s) in order, we can get deeper into your problem and can find the issue propertly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `equation` variable is undefined in the function trying to calculate the value. Do some debugging to make sure `equation` is a globally defined scope, or even better, try writing a function `getEquation()` that retrieves it when the equals button is clicked.

For debugging, you should think "hmm, if num is undefined, then where does that come from?"... `num` comes from `equation`... "what's `equation`?... adding `console.log()`s along the way should help trace it down.